# Can I sue a car garage for only offering cash payment?

Tags: contract-law, landlord, tenant, rent, car

I rent a parking spot in a garage in NYC for my car. Rent payment is made only in cash. When I joined 2 years ago, owner told me he would set up electronic payments or will accept Zelle payments, in the event it is still not available. Now he refuses to take payment by Zelle and asks me to pay in advance the rent before I travel, or pay a late fee at my return.
What can I do in that case? Is there a legal option I can seek to remedy this situation?

Comment: Sue them for what?  What wrong or damage have you suffered?  It seems that you simply prefer to pay by a different method.

Comment: no but you can park your car somewhere else, which is certain if you choose to sue them.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I sue a car garage for only offering cash payment?

Probably not.

A statement that new payment will be offered at some indefinite time in the future isn't specific enough to create a binding obligation to provide that service.

Even if there was a promise to provide, e.g., Zelle payment by January 1, 2024, your remedy would probably be limited to a declaration that you are allowed to terminate the rental arrangement going forward. You haven't suffered any economic damages from the policy.

Comment: Got it. I haven't suffered any economic damages so far. I signed up however under the illusion I could pay the rent electronically while I am traveling. I can't always organize my travels around the first 5 of the days and his refusal to accept my Zelle payment looks to me a simple attempt to extort more money from me (with his late fee).

Comment: @Lou Get a trusted buddy to give the guy a sealed envelope full of cash in the correct amount in the five day period while you are gone. You'll owe your buddy a beer or coffee when you get back and regale your friend with the glories of your trip. Old school problems have old school solutions. If you have no one you trust to do that, that is a different kind of problem.

Comment: haha. Yeah, I guess I will do that. 
I am just so upset with the garage owner. Can't stand NY scumbags! lol

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than a garage having a credit card only payment system.  Technically you can try to sue anyone or anything for any reason but this would be a waste of time as it would likely be thrown out before it gets anywhere